# ways to pivoting data and render the result to HTML in Django

Tags: python, django, pivot

I have the data looks like:

```
ws=[{'a': datetime.date(2020, 8, 31), 'b': <BB: 01>, 'c': <CC: 4>},
    {'a': datetime.date(2020, 8, 31), 'b': <BB: 01>, 'c': <CC: 5>},
    {'a': datetime.date(2020, 8, 31), 'b': <BB: 01>, 'c': <CC: 6>},
    {'a': datetime.date(2020, 8, 31), 'b': <BB: 02>, 'c': <CC: 9>},
    {'a': datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), 'b': <BB: 01>, 'c': <CC: 4>},
    {'a': datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), 'b': <BB: 01>, 'c': <CC: 5>},
    {'a': datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), 'b': <BB: 02>, 'c': <CC: 3>}]
```

And i wish to make it look like next, then render it to HTML.

```
\ a 
b\ |2020-08-31| 2020-09-01|
---|----------|-----------|-----
01 |c= 4,5,6  |c= 4,5     | 
02 |c= 9      |c= 3       |
```

Even though spending days of effort, i still do not have any
idea. If someone can kindly give me some guidance, i will
very very appreciate.

Comment: Can you use pandas? its pivoting functionality is robust.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur kindly advice. Per ur recommendation, i had tried the pandas,"pivot_table," but get the error message "not supported between instances of 'cc' and 'cc'. I cannot figure out what happen on it. Could you give me some more details guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Working from your dictionary called `ws`:

```
import pandas as pd

# convert the dic w to a dataframe: 
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ws)

# cast dataframe column types 
pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='%Y-%m0%d'))))
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(str)
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(str)

# pivot, (a) changing the default aggfunc to join the strings (b)
# set the column to be a, the index to be b: 
df.pivot_table(columns='a', values='c', index='b', aggfunc={'c':lambda x: " ".join(x)}).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
a                      2020-08-31       2020-09-01
b
<BB: 01>  <CC: 4> <CC: 5> <CC: 6>  <CC: 4> <CC: 5>
<BB: 02>                  <CC: 9>          <CC: 3>
```

To render the dataframe in html, just use:

```
df.to_html()
```